# Tkinter : How to change position of text on image

Tags: python, tkinter

I have developed some application on my laptop with python and tkinter. Then, I was stuck at some point. Question is : how can I change text position on image.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

path_to_pic = "....."
root = tk.Tk()
pic = Image.open(path_to_pic)
tkpic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic)
tk.Label(root, image = tkpic, text = ".....", compound = tk.CENTER).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This shows that my text appears on the picture, only on the center. I would like to move my text little by little and find best position. Do you know any solution or similar way to achieve this ?

Comment: How to fill old text space ?

Comment: You can move text horizontally by adding spaces to any side you wish.

Comment: And for vertical movement you can use '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

You can move text horizontally and vertically by adding spaces and '\n's respectively, to any side(s) of the text you wish:

```
text = "caption         \n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

This will put "caption" at the top left of the text.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It seems that there is no way to move text with grid, place and pack method. But, I could achieve what I wanted to do. Cheers.